# gcc and gfortran is incompatiable

Tags: gcc, homebrew, gfortran

I am using MACOS Big Sur.
I installed the gcc 9 by

```
brew install gcc@9
```

But I found my gfortran is gfortran8.2. So I uninstall the gfortran  and reinstall it by

```
brew install gfortran
```

But the version is
bash-3.2$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0_4) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty;

How I can install a gfortran9(link to gcc@9) by brew in Mac

Comment: Can you please provide the error that you get by installing gfortran?

Comment: No mistake for installation... Just the gfortran and gcc have  different versions. Then I use other software which needs both gcc9 and gfortran9 will show an error message.

Comment: From what I can see that specific version is not available, you might want to take a look at this https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS